# Android studio error after installation

Tags: 16.04, android, android-studio, android-sdk

When i start a new project or application on the android studio, the screen is stuck at making a new project and the terminal (from where the studio.sh was started) i constantly outputting a "." every second and eating up my cpu, what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

That's just android studio downloading some files. The "gradle" if I recall correctly. So just wait for it to complete.

And after that you'll need to download even more stuff. Things like the "NDK" which is more than half a Gigabyte. Some downloads don't inform you of the progress. And it can happen that android studio is just frozen and you need to close it and open it again.

You have to be very patient with android studio at first, but once it pulls through everything should work fine.

Comment: But it crashes down my computer every time, and i have let it happen for a few times now, it just doesn't complete.

Comment: to me the dots just took some time, then it finished and went to the next step. Do you get some error message in the terminal?